# Custom object report is working for admin user but not for other user

Tags: reports-api

I have created report in custom object admin user working fine but another user not working

i have created permission set all fileds are access but not working

Comment: Are you not able to see the report under reports folder or you are not able to see actual data in the report?

Comment: iam not able to see the actual data in that report

Comment: Alright that means your report is visible but data is not coming, please check following things:
1. Sharing rules on that custom object
2. profile and Permission for that particular user
3. Check your report characteristics sometimes we add Default View as "recently viewed" or "My records", instead of all records